Elastic query that harvests all indexes with a field that has a specific data type
I am getting mapping conflicts in elastic. The field in question needs to be a float, however its getting mapped as a keyword.
I need a query that can harvest all indexes that have this field. I want a command that can show me all indexes that have this field as a float and all that have this field as a keyword. Must include @timestamp as well so I can narrow down when these indexes were created. Note: these are metric data streams.
How can I accomplish this?

There is no specific command to do all of it at once but you can do step by step and automate it with shell script, python or something similar.

Find all indices that have field_name field in the mapping.

GET _all/_mapping/field/field_name?filter_path=**.field_name


After find all indices that have field_name sort them by creation date.

GET _cat/indices/test,test-3,test-4?v&h=index,pri,rep,docs.count,cds&s=cds:desc

Note: If the field is a sub field or it's not indexed like flattened field type it won't be visible in the mapping, so you can't find it.

